# Is the boundary of a ball in a Riemannian manifold a smooth curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Assume that $g$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $g'$ be another smooth metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that there are constants $a,b>0$ such that for every $z \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $v \in T_z (\mathbb{R}^2) \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$ we have
$$
a \langle v,v\rangle_{g} \leq \langle v,v \rangle_{g'} \leq b\langle v,v\rangle_{g}.
$$

In such a *nice* situation, what can we say about the boundary of the  balls in $M = (\mathbb{R}^2,g')$? More specifically, can we say that the boundary of any ball in $M$ is a smooth (or piecewise smooth) curve?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about the implicit function theorem? Note that you're requiring $g'$ to be smooth.

Comment: @April It might be worth cautioning that that argument won't work globally, since $f$ may fail to be smooth at points beyond the injectivity radius of $0$.

Comment: @Kajelad Thanks! You are right. My calculations in my previous comment were actually wrong, hence deleted it. This post (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977849/gradient-of-distance-squared-on-riemannian-manifold) gives the exact gradient of $f$ in the ball with at $0$ with radius the infectivity radius.

Comment: It also might be worth noting that there  are counterexamples in which $\partial B_{g'}(x,r)$ fails to be a smooth curve if $r$ is allowed to exceed the injectivity radius of $x$. It can, for instance, have self-intersections or cusps. Your inequality also doesn't do anything to control the injectivity radius, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Kajelad Are there any "standard and easy" counterexamples? Or is it more of a contrived one? Thanks!

Comment: @AprilI I don't know of a counterexample which makes the calculation easy, but problems will tend to arise whenever you have conjugate points. The example I was thinking of was adding a smooth "bump" compactly supported away from zero ($g'(x)=(1+\psi(x))g(x)$), so that the geodesic balls switch from disks to annuli around the bump.

Comment: Or consider a "cigar"-shaped manifold consisting of a one-sided infinite cylinder with a spherical cap.