# Smoothness of the Fréchet Function on Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, non-convex-optimization, noneuclidean-geometry, information-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold and let $d$ be the induced distance function on $M$. Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $M$ with continuous density. The Fr$\acute{\mathrm{e}}$chet function is defined as

$$
F_{\mu}(x) = \int_{M} d^2(x,y) \,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)
$$

I want to ask whether $F_{\mu}(x)$ is a smooth, or a $\mu$-almost surely smooth function on $M$? Does the regularity of $F_{\mu}(x)$ depend on the regularity of the density function of $\mu$?

For any fixed $x\in M$, the squared distance function $r_x(\cdot):=d^2(x,\cdot)$ is a $\mu$-almost surely smooth function (it is not differentiable on the cut locus of $x$). The gradient of $r_x$ is given by $\nabla r_x(y) = -2\exp_y^{-1}(x)$ (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977849/gradient-of-distance-squared-on-riemannian-manifold)). I feel that (might be wrong) the function $F_\mu(x)$ is continuously differentiable, and the gradient is given by

$$
\langle \nabla F(x),v \rangle_x = -2\int_M\langle \exp_x^{-1}(y),v \rangle_x\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)
$$

where $v\in T_xM$ is any tangent vector at $x$.

I'm also looking for examples where an explicity computation of $F_\mu(x)$ is possible, as a way to verify the above question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try to work out some examples, for instance the case when $M=S^1$ or a flat torus?

Comment: Yes I tried $M=S^1$. I also find there is a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.1986) with very detailed computation (with general assumption on probability measures). It seems the regularity of Frechet function depends on the regularity of density function but I cannot see why it is the case in general setting.

Comment: So, what was the answer in the circle case?

Comment: In the reference paper if you look at equation (3.1), roughly the derivative is a linear term plus/minus the measure of an interval. With continuous density function we can further differentiate so the second derivative of the Frechet function exists and is continuous. But without further assumption we can take no more derivatives.